# Two matrices related by a permutation $B = P A P^T$ - complexity

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, cg.comp-geom, linear-algebra, permutations

What is computational complexity of the following problem:

given two complex $n\times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ check if there is a permutation matrix $P$ such that:
$$B = P A P^T.$$

If it helps, one can assume that $A$ and $B$ are hermitian (or even that $A$ and $B$ are real and symmetric).

Notes:

The problem stems from checking if two sets of vectors are related by an unitary rotation, see [Sets of vectors related by a rotation - MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/101694/sets-of-vectors-related-by-a-rotation). In that context $A$ and $B$ are their [Gramian matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix).

The problem is at least as hard as the [graph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) - take $A$ and $B$ as adjacency matrices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is equivalent to deciding whether two given multigraphs (or edge-labelled graphs) are isomorphic or not, which is known to be equivalent to the usual graph isomorphism problem.